# Check the string with hash key

Tags: ruby

I am using Ruby 1.9.

I have a hash:

```
Hash_List={"ruby"=>"fun to learn","the rails"=>"It is a framework"}
```

I have a string like this:

```
test_string="I am learning the ruby by myself and also the rails."
```

I need to check if `test_string` contains words that match the keys of `Hash_List`. And if it does, replace the words with the matching hash value.

I used this code to check, but it is returning them empty:

```
another_hash=Hash_List.select{|key,value| key.include? test_string}
```

Comment: `a.include? "B"` = is "B" a substring of a? So what you want is `test_string.include? key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, hold onto your hat:

```
HASH_LIST = {
  "ruby" => "fun to learn",
  "the rails" => "It is a framework"
}

test_string = "I am learning the ruby by myself and also the rails."

keys_regex = /\b (?:#{Regexp.union(HASH_LIST.keys).source}) \b/x # => /\b (?:ruby|the\ rails) \b/x
test_string.gsub(keys_regex, HASH_LIST) # => "I am learning the fun to learn by myself and also It is a framework."
```

Ruby's got some great tricks up its sleeve, one of which is how we can throw a regular expression and a hash at [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub), and it'll search for every match of the regular expression, look up the matching "hits" as keys in the hash, and substitute the values back into the string:

```
gsub(pattern, hash) → new_str
```

> ...If the second argument is a Hash, and the matched text is one of its keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string....

```
Regexp.union(HASH_LIST.keys) # => /ruby|the\ rails/
Regexp.union(HASH_LIST.keys).source # => "ruby|the\\ rails"
```

Note that the first returns a regular expression and the second returns a string. This is important when we embed them into another regular expression:

```
/#{Regexp.union(HASH_LIST.keys)}/ # => /(?-mix:ruby|the\ rails)/
/#{Regexp.union(HASH_LIST.keys).source}/ # => /ruby|the\ rails/
```

The first can quietly destroy what you think is a simple search, because of the `?-mix:` flags, which ends up embedding different flags inside the pattern.

The [Regexp documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html) covers all this well.

This capability is the core to making an extremely high-speed templating routine in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

First, follow naming conventions. Variables are `snake_case`, and names of classes are `CamelCase`.

```
hash = {"ruby" => "fun to learn", "rails" => "It is a framework"}
words = test_string.split(' ') # => ["I", "am", "learning", ...]
another_hash = hash.select{|key,value| words.include?(key)}
```

Answering your question: split your test string in words with [`#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) and then check whether words include a key.

For checking if the string is substring of another string use `String#[String]` method:

```
another_hash = hash.select{|key, value| test_string[key]}
```

Comment: Regarding "constants are CamelCase".  Class and module names should be CamelCase; other constants should be in [SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming).

Comment: Fair enough, I will fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks @EugZol for answer and suggestion about naming convention.In my above hash you see there is another key "the rails".Is it possible to check that key with string as we did for single word?

Comment: Variables and methods in Ruby are not "lower_case", they're "snake_case". Lowercase would be "somethinglikethis".

Answer (score 0):

You could do that as follows:

```
Hash_List.each_with_object(test_string.dup) { |(k,v),s| s.sub!(/#{k}/, v) } 
 #=> "I am learning the fun to learn by myself and also It is a framework."
```